# Why fragment not working

Tags: android

I want to change text in a textview in fragment , I can do this easily in instantiateItem , but after instantiateItem , textView is null and I can not call with

MyPagerAdapter.textView.SetText();

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


        TextView textView;

        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            int resId = 0;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.farleft;
                 View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
                 textView = (TextView)view.findviewById(R.id.textvvvv);
                 return view;

            case 1:
                resId = R.layout.left;
                break;
            case 2:
                resId = R.layout.middle;
                break;
            case 3:
                resId = R.layout.right;
                break;
            case 4:
                resId = R.layout.farright;
                break;
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
            ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }
}
```

But , the starnge is here when I change text in instantiateItem with

```
textView.SetText("EEE");
```

it works well , but I can not change text outside MyPageAdapter, why ?

Comment: Have you tried ((TextView)getAdapter().findViewById(R.id.textvvvv)).setTextView("EEE")

Comment: adapter_Viewpager adapter = new adapter_Viewpager(); and adapter.getAdapter do not have findViewById ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyPagerAdapter` is not `static` and your access method is to be used for static classes. Try instantiating the `PagerAdapter` and use that reference to call the `getAdapter()` method and try to locate the view using the `findViewById(....)`

**EDIT:**

When you declare your `PagerAdapter` in your activity, from that try to get the reference of the adapter from it, something like below

`PagerAdapter viewer = (PagerAdapter) findViewById(R.id.pageradapter);` -->

```
viewer.getAdapter().findViewById(...)
```

Comment: adapter_Viewpager adapter = new adapter_Viewpager(); and adapter.getAdapter do not have findViewById

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager inherits findViewById() from View, so can't you just do:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) viewPager.findViewById(...);
```